# Plotly: disable hovering on surface plot

Tags: python, plotly

With plotly I am able to plot a 3D cylinder surface using `go.Surface(...)`. Besides this cylinder trace I have a second trace with additional data points from a 3D scatter plot `go.Scatter3d(...)` on the final plot. These data have a lower radius than the surface cylinder:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

def data_for_cylinder_along_z(center_x,center_y,radius,height_z):
    z = np.linspace(0, height_z, 50)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
    theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, z)
    x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
    y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
    return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

Xc,Yc,Zc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,100,3600)
cyl = go.Surface(x=Zc_o, y=Yc_o, z=Xc_o, 
                   colorscale = 'Blues', 
                   showscale=False, opacity=0.2)


dots = go.Scatter3d(x=[240,869,2709,3001],
                       y=[30,60,83,25],
                       z =[35,40,29,27],
                      )

layout = go.Layout(scene = dict(aspectmode = "manual", 
                                aspectratio = dict(x=2, y=0.3, z=0.3),
                               ),
                  )

fig = go.Figure(data=[
                      cyl,
                      dots,
                     ],
                layout=layout,
               )

fig.show()
```

Now I want to get information for **each scattered data point** inside the cylinder by hovering over the plotly plot - but I have no access to these data. The hovering is stucked at the surface of the outer cylinder, I cannot get any information from inside.
If the `cyl`-Statement is removed from `fig=go.Figure(...)` the hovering works as desired.

Is there a possibility to disable the hovering for the outer cylinder surface in plotly?

I tried to use internal plotly parameters like

```
hovertemplate=None
hoverinfo = 'skip'
contours=go.surface.Contours(
                       x=go.surface.contours.X(highlight=False))
```

but without success.

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319619/disable-hover-information-on-trace-plotly). They omit the hover template. `cyl = go.Surface(x=Zc, y=Yc, z=Xc, colorscale = 'Blues', showscale=False, opacity=0.2, hoverinfo='skip')
`

Comment: @r-beginners: Already tried. Setting the hoverinfo parameter that way results in not showing the according (x, y, z) information but the cursor still stucks at the outer cylinder surface.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one. It looks like there is no solution at the moment

https://community.plotly.com/t/completely-excluding-a-trace-from-hover-info-snapping/35854

Edit: changing the theta range to

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*0.8, 50)
```

to remove a segment:

[image: Plot with segment removed]

Comment: Thank you - that comforts me very much ;-) By the way: I remember the link, stumbled over it during my recherche...

Comment: If the full cylinder is not necessary for the understanding of the graph, you could consider leaving out a segment so you can "look into" it and get the mouse hover on. Maybe leave out a slice of 30-60 degrees (roughly from 12 o'clock to 2 o'clock)

Comment: Very nice idea. But unfortunately, in reality I have so much dots inside distributed over the hole angular range, that this wouldn't work productively.

Comment: You could add a range slider widget to select the angle over which the cylinder needs to be shown/opened ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of the former answer, I replaced the cylinder surface by a stack of contours:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

def data_for_cylinder_along_z(center_x,center_y,radius,height_z):
    z = np.linspace(0, height_z, 50)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
    theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, z)
    x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
    y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
    return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

def boundary_circle(r, h, nt=100):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, nt)
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)
    z = h*np.ones(theta.shape)
    return x, y, z

cyl_dia = 100
cyl_len = 3600
frac = 100

Xc,Yc,Zc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,cyl_dia,cyl_len)
xb, yb, zb = boundary_circle(cyl_dia, h=0)
x_cont, y_cont, z_cont = [], [], []
for i in range(0,frac):
    x_cont += [val for val in xb] + [None]
    y_cont += [val for val in yb] + [None]
    z_cont += [val + i*cyl_len/frac for val in zb] + [None]
x_cont += [val for val in xb]
y_cont += [val for val in yb]
z_cont += [val + cyl_len for val in zb_low]

cyl = go.Surface(x=Zc_o, y=Yc_o, z=Xc_o, 
                 colorscale = 'Blues', 
                 showscale=False, opacity=0.2, 
#                  hoverinfo='skip'
                )

cyl_contour = go.Scatter3d(
                     x=z_cont, y=y_cont, z=x_cont,                   
                     hovertemplate=None,
                     hoverinfo = 'skip',
                     mode ='lines',
                     line = dict(color='blue', width=2),
                     opacity=0.15
                    )

dots = go.Scatter3d(x=[240,869,2709,3001],
                       y=[30,60,83,25],
                       z =[35,40,29,27],
                      )

layout = go.Layout(scene = dict(aspectmode = "manual", 
                                aspectratio = dict(x=2, y=0.3, z=0.3),
                               ),
#                    hovermode=False,
                   hoverdistance=0
                  )

fig = go.Figure(data=[
#                       cyl,
                      cyl_contour,
                      dots,
                     ],
                layout=layout,
               )

fig.show()
```

This is ok for my purpose (even if it does not completely satisfy me...)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn1SH.png)